# Hashmap sorting based on the sort index of a arraylist

Tags: java, android, sorting, hashmap

I am working with firebase database. And from the firebase get some data. i want to display the data in a listview. Document from the firebase include 3 fields. each of the field include date,heading and description. and i want to display data in descending order of the date.

i just called Collection.sort(datelist) But only the date sorted. rest of them stay as random.

```java
private void eventforloop() {
    for (z = 0; z < jas1.length; z++) {
        jas1[z] = jas1[z].trim();

        DocumentReference data = db.collection("schools").document(Sname).collection("anouncements").document(jas1[z]);
        data.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    adate = String.valueOf(documentSnapshot.get("date")).trim();
                    adescr = String.valueOf(documentSnapshot.get("desc")).trim();
                    aheaing = String.valueOf(documentSnapshot.get("heading")).trim();

                    datelist.add(adate);
                    desclist.add(adescr);
                    headinglist.add(aheaing);

                    newEvent();
                }
        });
    }
}

public void newEvent() {
    for (int p = 0; p < datelist.size(); p++) {
        customClass = new CustomClass();
        customClass.setAdate(getDate(adate));
        customClass.setAdescr(adescr);
        customClass.setAheaing(aheaing);

        ArrayList<CustomClass> newList = new ArrayList<CustomClass>();
        newList.add(customClass);

        Collections.sort(newList, new Comparator<CustomClass>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(CustomClass o1, CustomClass o2) {
                    return o1.getAdate().compareTo(o2.getAdate());
                }
        });

        UsersAdapter usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(getApplicationContext(), newList);
        anouncement_list.setAdapter(usersAdapter);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

public class UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomClass> {
    public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CustomClass> customClass) {
        super(context, 0, customClass);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.anouncementxml1, parent, false);
        }

        // Lookup view for data population
        TextView tDate = convertView.findViewById(R.id.anndate);
        TextView theading = convertView.findViewById(R.id.annheading);
        JustifiedTextView tdesc = convertView.findViewById(R.id.anndescri);
        CustomClass customClass = getItem(position);

        android.text.format.DateFormat df = new android.text.format.DateFormat();
        tDate.setText(df.format("dd-MM-yyyy",customClass.adate).toString());
        theading.setText(customClass.aheaing);
        tdesc.setText(customClass.adescr);
        return convertView;
    }
}

private Date getDate(String yooo) {
    SimpleDateFormat spf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    Date newDate = null;
    try {
        newDate = spf.parse(yooo);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return newDate;
}
```

Comment: I do not understand your problem. You are sorting a specific list, that list is sorted, all other variables are untouched. That is what you expect if you sort a list without side effects. In heading, you mention a HashMap; there is no HashMap in you code. Can you explain you problem clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED AFTER ALL COMMENTS**

```
ArrayList<CustomClass> newList = new ArrayList<CustomClass>();

    private void eventforloop() {
        final UsersAdapter usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(getApplicationContext(), newList);
        anouncement_list.setAdapter(usersAdapter);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        for (z = 0; z < jas1.length; z++) {
            jas1[z] = jas1[z].trim();

            DocumentReference data = db.collection("schools").document(Sname).collection("anouncements").document(jas1[z]);
            data.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    String adate = String.valueOf(documentSnapshot.get("date")).trim();
                    String adescr = String.valueOf(documentSnapshot.get("desc")).trim();
                    String aheaing = String.valueOf(documentSnapshot.get("heading")).trim();

                    CustomClass customClass = new CustomClass();
                    customClass.setAdate(getDate(adate));
                    customClass.setAdescr(adescr);
                    customClass.setAheaing(aheaing);

                    newList.add(customClass);
                    Collections.sort(newList, new Comparator<CustomClass>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(CustomClass o1, CustomClass o2) {
                            return o1.getAdate().compareTo(o2.getAdate());
                        }
                    });

                    usersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

        }

    }

    public class UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomClass> {
        public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CustomClass> customClass) {
            super(context, 0, customClass);
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Get the data item for this position

            // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.anouncementxml1, parent, false);
            }

            // Lookup view for data population
            TextView tDate = convertView.findViewById(R.id.anndate);
            TextView theading = convertView.findViewById(R.id.annheading);
            JustifiedTextView tdesc = convertView.findViewById(R.id.anndescri);
            CustomClass customClass = getItem(position);

            android.text.format.DateFormat df = new android.text.format.DateFormat();
            tDate.setText(df.format("dd-MM-yyyy",customClass.adate).toString());
            theading.setText(customClass.aheaing);
            tdesc.setText(customClass.adescr);
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    private Date getDate(String yooo) {
        SimpleDateFormat spf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        Date newDate = null;
        try {
            newDate = spf.parse(yooo);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return newDate;
    }
```

Comment: cannot resolve getDate in obj.setAdate(getDate(adate)); @faranjit

Comment: getDate(adate: String) is a method which takes a String as parameter and converts it to a Date object and returns Date.

Comment: may i do anything for getting this method in my project? @faranjith

Comment: :) `SimpleDateFormat spf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    Date newDate= null;
    try {
        newDate = spf.parse(yooo);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`

Comment: Doesnt work what? Does it not sort properly or does it not get date?

Comment: doesn't get date.  Cannot resolve method 'getDate(java.lang.String)' @faranjit

Comment: Updated answer, check it please

Comment: just a single line data only visible in listview. @faranjit

Comment: Do these in a loop that loops as much document as you get from firebase.

Comment: Are you receving a list from firebase? If so can you tell me the count?

Comment: 16 for each list @faranjit

Comment: Ok, last question. Can you post your last codes to question please?

Comment: Updated. pls check it.

Comment: Dude, you create a new list in every loop in `newEvent` method of course it is displayed for one item. Just move this line `    ArrayList<CustomClass> newList = new ArrayList<CustomClass>();
` out of `newEvent` method.

Comment: Now newlist(Arraylist) moved from there and placed after newEvent method calling. no changes in output.